# centering HTML output

Tags: html, css

How can I center the output of this?
I want is to the products in the boxes are in the center of the main body

```css
#nicebox {
 float: left;
 /*position: relative;*/
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 
}
```

```html
<h3>Popular Products</h3>

<?php
require_once('my_connect.php');

$my_query="select * from products limit 5"; 
$result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);

while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):

$description = $myrow["product_description"];
$price = $myrow["price"];
$image=$myrow["image"];

if($image):
echo "<div id=\"nicebox\"><a href=\"products/$image\" rel=\"lightbox[dp]\"  title=\"$description\" alt=\"Hello\"><img src=\"products/$image\" class=\"thumbnail\"></a></div>";

endif;

endwhile;

?>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: i hope you understand its nothing to do with php

Comment: php has nothing to do with centering. it is strictly html + css. you made `float: left;` - there is no centering. moreover, `display:block` (which is div by default) will take all possible width

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP; all the browser sees is the HTML and CSS, so if you know what the HTML needs to look like, outputting that with PHP is easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

```
#nicebox {
    /*position: relative;*/
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: thanks! I have multiple images on one line so doing that just stretches the entire box across however.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the PHP output in a `<div>` give it an id (e.g. #output) or class and add style to it.

```
#output {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```